# Cell Tap Doesn't Work on didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: swift, parse-platform, swift2, didselectrowatindexpath, parseui

I'm using Parse.com to build my app.

I initialized a `PFQueryTableViewController` as my subclass.

I'm unable to tap the indexPath.row so that the cell leads to another viewController and passes data.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

       print("tapped")
        //Nothing prints. The simulator cell doesn't even change color as it normally does... 

}
```

In a normal project without Parse, I tap and it leads me to where I want it to lead. I don't understand why that doesn't work here.

I referenced several links, such as:

1. https://www.parse.com/questions/pfquerytableview-didselect-row-open-pbobject-in-uiwebview (outdated and objective-c)
2. https://www.parse.com/questions/using-pfquerytableviewcontroller-in-detail-view (didn't work)
3. [didSelectRowAtIndexPath method at PFQueryTableViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28570869/didselectrowatindexpath-method-at-pfquerytableviewcontroller) (also didn't work)

None have helped.

Im also trying to use a UIGestureecognizer on the view from the custom cell. This isn't helping either...

This is the attributes inspector:

http://postimg.org/image/3omx3serh/

I've selected and deselected the relevant parts. Nothing works.

EDIT: I'm also using an initializer:

```
 override init(style: UITableViewStyle, className: String!)
    {
        super.init(style: style, className: className)

        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = true
        self.paginationEnabled = false
        self.objectsPerPage = 25

        self.parseClassName = className
        self.tableView.rowHeight = 120
        self.tableView.allowsSelection = false
    }

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

Any idea why I can't tap cell? Any ideas on how to tap the cell?

Comment: Do you have a uibutton or something else that could be receiving the tap and not passing down to your cell?

Comment: It should be the cell itself. didSelectRowAtIndexPath should be triggering a segue to another viewController. Or even being recognized that a cell exists. The cellForRowAtIndexPath works and it prints on the UI different labels and buttons. But i want the cell itself to capture a touch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also using an initializer that I'm accessing. This PFTableViewController I'm building only in code. For those building in code and not in the storyboard, make sure `self.tableView.allowsSelection = true`. Saw other links experiencing similar problems. Here the full code of the initializer:

```
override init(style: UITableViewStyle, className: String!)
{
    super.init(style: style, className: className)

    self.pullToRefreshEnabled = true
    self.paginationEnabled = false
    self.objectsPerPage = 25

    self.parseClassName = className
    self.tableView.rowHeight = 120
    self.tableView.allowsSelection = true
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

Realized that `self.tableView.allowsSelection = false` was set to false instead of true.

I set it to true and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I would check if your Table View has "User Interaction Enabled" enabled inside Attribute Inspector.

Secondly I would examine which class has been inserted inside your View Controller's Identity Inspector.

Comment: I'm creating the cell in a XIB file. The cell is the correct class and it's the class that I'm referencing in the `PFQueryTableViewController`. Check my updated answer